# What is a good resource I can reference to learn all about lubricants and sprays?

Tags: maintenance

I think we can all agree that there are tons of lube products for screws, for belts, and for other car components and I cannot differentiate between them and I never know what to use in a given situation. For example:

What is the difference of:

- WD 40
- Penetrating oil
- Anti-seize lubricant
- Die electric grease
- Sil glyde
- Silicone Lube
- Joint grease
- Solvents vs lubricants
- Thread locker
- Belt dressing

These are only some of them of course. If anyone has a comprehensive reference guide, let me know thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one resource guide that can cover such a big subject: it is the Internet! But you need to be organized and patient. You have already started making a list of subjects. As you discover new subjects and products, add them to the list and prioritize the list according to which products interest the most. Then read Wiki pages on those subjects. Use Google images to scan product pictures and discover brands, then add them to your list. In time you will have your own comprehensive guide. You can also use the search function in various forums to see how others use their products.

Comment: But be careful... as Abraham Lincoln said, *"the Internet is filled with half truths and lies"*.